# How to access defined URL in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have controller `UserController` and action `actionAjax`. I access by Chrome with below URL and it is working normally.

```
index.php?r=user/ajax
```

Now I define new action with named `actionAjaxUser`, still using Chrome to access URL `index.php?user/ajaxUser`

Then 404 returned.
What should I do to getting content of `actionAjaxUser`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add for each additional uppercase Letter after "action" a "-" so in your case

`index.php?r=user/ajax-user`

So if you would have an action like `actionTest1Test2Test3` the url would be `controllername/test1-test2-test3`.

Be aware that if you are using access rules you also have to use the "url" path.

```
return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['test1-test2-test3'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

The same Naming scheme is btw. also used for Controllers. E.g. if your Controller is named `Test1Test2Controller` the view folder name would be `test1-test2`.

Hope this clarifies this for you.